# An iff condition for the existence of a $\Gamma$- invariant sub-algebra of $C(X)$

Tags: group-theory, dynamical-systems, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

There is an action of $\Gamma$ on a compact Hausdorff space $X$. The question is to find an iff condition for the existence of a $\Gamma$ invariant sub-algebra of $C(X)$. I started out with the following:

> > Suppose that $\Gamma$ acts on a compact Hausdroff space $X$. There exists a $\Gamma$-invariant subalgebra of $C(X)$ iff there exists an injective $\Gamma$-equivariant map from a $\Gamma$-space $A$ to $C(X)$.

Suppose that $B$ is an invariant subalgebra of $C(X)$. Let $j: B \to C(X)$ be the inclusion map. Then $j$ is injective. Moreover $j(s.b)=s.b=s.j(b)$. So $j$ is $\Gamma$-equivariant.

On the other hand suppose that there is an injective $\Gamma$-equivariant map $\phi$ from a  $\Gamma$-space $A$ to $C(X)$. Then $\phi(A)$ is a subset of $C(X)$. Moreover $s.\phi(a)=\phi(s.a) \in \phi(A) \subset C(X)$. Thus $\phi(A)$ is $\Gamma$-invariant.

But then I realized that $\phi(A)$ is not necessarily a sub algebra of $C(X)$. To make it a subalgebra I have to impose a condition on $\phi$. So I thought of making $\phi$ a linear homomorphism. Then this establishes the claim.

I want to know if this is optimal in the sense that if there can be any other condition weaker than what I have got here.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Does the subalgebra generated by $\phi(A)$ not do the trick?

Comment: I would have to still take the map to be linear. Is not it?

Comment: The action of $\Gamma$ on $C(X)$ is by $*$-automorphisms, so if the action is invariant for $\phi(A)$ (which it is since $\phi$ is $\Gamma$-equivariant), it should be invariant for the subalgebra generated by $\phi(A)$.

Comment: I see. It is enough to have the injective Gamma equivariant map then.

Comment: You have your map going in the wrong direction.  An imbedding $C(Y) \to C(X)$ corresponds to a surjective map from $X$ to $Y$.   Basically for the same reason, by the way, and action of $\Gamma$ by $*$ automorphisms of $C(X)$  is induced by an action of $\Gamma$  by homeomorphisms of $X$.

Comment: So I should have a map from $C(X)$ to $C(Y)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: So the map has to be surjective then?

Comment: I don't see a fault in my argument though